# Vaadin grid selected row color

Tags: background, grid, vaadin

Searched a lot to change the default selected row background color of Vaadin 24 grid with CSS,
tried

```
vaadin-grid::part(selected-row) {
  background: orange;
}
```

but it is not working.

I am able to change selected row font color with

```
vaadin-grid::part(selected-row) {
      color: blue;
    }
```

somebody please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that the *cells* define their own background color, so you need to override that instead with `vaadin-grid::part(selected-row-cell)`

Comment: Correct answer with good explanation, working fine.

Comment: Can you please answer my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845281/vaddin-payment-gateway-integration-razorpay)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it like this:

```
vaadin-grid::part(selected-row) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff8800, #ff8800);
}
```

Comment: It is also not working. Even though I am very glad knowing that my question has been answered by a vaadin expert.

Comment: Can you please answer my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845281/vaddin-payment-gateway-integration-razorpay)